# Number of Records Per Hour by Category

Tags: sas

I'm struggling conceptualizing a code I would like to develop that would output the average number of patients seen by provider. Here is what a snippet of what my dataset, which spans 3 years worth of data, looks like (I have three variables, the patient_ID, provider name and the time which the provider saw the patient which is displayed in a date/time format:

```
 patient_fin     first_Md_seen   Provider_Seen_Date_Time
   1                 Bob              5/1/2018 4:19:00  AM
   2                 Bob              5/1/2018 4:29:00  AM
   3                 Bob              5/1/2018 4:30:00  PM
   4                 Sally            5/1/2018 7:39:00  AM
   5                 Sally            5/1/2018 7:49:00  AM
   6                 Sally            5/1/2018 8:55:00  PM
   7                 Bubba            5/3/2018 12:19:00 AM
   8                 Bob              5/3/2018 4:10:00  AM
   ....
```

To calculate the number of a patients seen by a provider, I wrote the following code:

```
 data ED_TAT3;
 SET ED_TAT2;
 if patient_fin ne . then Patient_fin_count=1;
 run;

 proc means data = ED_TAT3;
 class first_Md_seen;
 var Patient_fin_count;
 run;
```

Now, I need to figure out how many hours a provider worked so I can divide the number of patients seen by the number of hours worked.

I think I can use the Provider_Seen_Date_Time variable as a proxy after running the following code to get the hour 'hour = hour (datepart(Provider_Seen_Date_Time))'.

Would a code like this give me the correct number of hours a provider

```
 data new1;
 set new;
 hour = hour (datepart(Provider_Seen_Date_Time));
 if Provider_Name = 'Bob' and hour ne . then hour_worked = 1;
 run;
```

Is there:

1) a more accurate or efficient (there are hundreds of different providers) way to figure out the total number of hours worked per provider?

OR

2) which is the more ideal code, to simply figure out the number of patients per hour a provider saw.

Desired output:

```
       Provider        Avg Patients Seen per Hour 
         Bob                         5
         Sally                       4
         Bubba                       6
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the dataset that you provided is accurate? I can't seem to find patient_fin, first_Md_seen variables.. Also, would it be possible to provide more observations for a single provider? Example - Bob, Sally etc.

Comment: Sorry just changed the patient_fin and first_md_seen variables to align the the dataset-it is now accurate. It is possible for a provider to see more than one patient per hour. For example, Bob could potentially see 1 patient in an hour or 4 patients in a given hour.

Comment: How do we determine *how many hours a provider worked* without a start or end time for duration? What part of work hours do those time stamps signify? Do we assume provider works at beginning to end of that hour of time stamp?

Comment: Also, the first two obs of dataset for Bob share same date, but time is different (4:19 AM, 4:30 PM). So technically are different hours in morning and evening

Comment: @Parfait I was thinking we determine the number of hours a provider worked through if he saw a patient in a given hour. For example, if the Provider_Seen_Date_Time variable showed he treated one patient at 1pm, 3 patients at 2pm and 7 patients at 3pm and 0 patients for all other hours of the day, we can assume that the provider worked 3 hours (1-3PM).

Comment: @Rhythm . Yes that is correct Bob saw two patients that day so we can assume he worked two hours (4pm and 4am) on 5/1/2018. I know this inst a perfect way to calculate the number of hours worked but this will at least provide the best estimate.

Comment: For counts use the SUM for duration use the RANGE calculation, by date. Can a provider work overnight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what is given , you can try following code.. however, I still have concerns about the data

```
data ed_tat2;
input patient_fin first_Md_seen$ Provider_Seen_Date_Time mdyampm25.2;
format Provider_Seen_Date_Time mdyampm25.;
hour = hour (Provider_Seen_Date_Time);
date_seen=datepart(Provider_Seen_Date_Time);
format date_seen date9.;

datalines;
1 Bob 5/1/2018 4:19:00 AM
2 Bob 5/1/2018 4:30:00 PM
3 Sally 5/1/2018 7:39:00 AM
4 Sally 5/1/2018 7:59:00 PM
5 Bubba 5/3/2018 12:19:00 AM
6 Bob 5/3/2018 4:10:00 AM
7 Bob 5/3/2018 4:30:00 AM
8 Bob 5/3/2018 5:10:00 AM
run;

proc sort data=ed_tat2; by first_Md_seen date_seen hour; run;

data ed_tat3;
 set ed_tat2;
  by first_Md_seen date_seen hour;
  if not first.first_Md_seen and date_seen=lag(date_seen) and hour=lag(hour) then hour=0;
  else hour=1;
run;

proc sql;
select first_Md_seen, date_seen, count(patient_fin) as number_of_patients_seen, sum(hour) as number_of_hours, count(patient_fin)/sum(hour) as patients_seen_per_hour
from ed_tat3
where hour ne .
group by first_Md_seen, date_seen;

select first_Md_seen, count(patient_fin) as number_of_patients_seen, sum(hour) as number_of_hours, count(patient_fin)/sum(hour) as patients_seen_per_hour
from ed_tat3
where hour ne .
group by first_Md_seen;
quit;
```

Comment: great!! happy to help

Comment: Hi again, I mostly understand how this code works-the only thing I'm curious about is the lag(date_seen). What exactly is this command instructing SAS to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily within two proc freqs.
The first will calculate the number of patients seen by doctor per hour and the second uses the first output to calculate the number of hours worked per doctor, per day. You can easily modify these by modifying the TABLE statements.

```
data ed_tat2;
    input patient_fin first_Md_seen $ Provider_Seen_Date_Time mdyampm25.2;
    format Provider_Seen_Date_Time mdyampm25.;
    hour=hour (Provider_Seen_Date_Time);
    date_seen=datepart(Provider_Seen_Date_Time);
    format date_seen date9.;
    datalines;
1 Bob 5/1/2018 4:19:00 AM
2 Bob 5/1/2018 4:30:00 PM
3 Sally 5/1/2018 7:39:00 AM
4 Sally 5/1/2018 7:59:00 PM
5 Bubba 5/3/2018 12:19:00 AM
6 Bob 5/3/2018 4:10:00 AM
7 Bob 5/3/2018 4:30:00 AM
8 Bob 5/3/2018 5:10:00 AM
;
run;

*counts per hour;

proc freq data=ed_tat2 noprint;
    table first_Md_seen*date_seen*hour / out=provider_counts;
run;

*hours worked per doctor;

proc freq data=provider_counts noprint;
    table first_Md_seen*date_seen / out=provider_hours;
run;

title 'Number of patients seen';

proc print data=provider_counts label;
    label count='# of patients per hour';
    title 'Number of hours worked';

proc print data=provider_hours label;
    label count='# of hours worked in a day';
run;
```